# When is it OK to inject the injector?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

If you take a look at the library I've been working on for [dependency injection in C++](https://bitbucket.org/cheez/dicpp/src/tip), I recently added [an example](https://bitbucket.org/cheez/dicpp/src/419adbb20c58/lib/examples/config/) that mimics something I created for a real project: the ability to inject application configuration directly.

This all works fine as the constructor just asks for a ConfigItem<ConfigTag> type and that is magically delivered.

A problem occurs when I need to access all of them at the same time (say for a configuration dialog).

The stupid solution I came up with was to generate, using the preprocessor, a class that gets all the configuration items in the constructor as shown [here](https://bitbucket.org/cheez/dicpp/src/419adbb20c58/lib/examples/config/AllConfigurationItems.hpp).

This problem would be "nicely" solved if I could inject the injector as I would then only have to generate the code to collect all the ConfigItem instances as shown [here](https://bitbucket.org/cheez/dicpp/src/419adbb20c58/lib/examples/config/AllConfigurationItems.cpp).

Note that all the ConfigItems are within a singleton scope.

Hope this question makes sense: how would you do this?

Comment: From the description this sounds conceptually like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891778/injecting-the-dependency-injector-using-dependency-injection I'm not a C++ programmer though, so I might be mistaken.

Comment: I think it's similar but I must imagine there are better answers!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have re-invented the [Service Locator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)

Comment: I don't like that one! That's why I'm not sure about how I could do this better. It's either generate a class with explicit dependencies (there could be hundreds in principle!), or generate the code that makes this dependency implicit.